# Likes for multiple posts on page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to workout how to like a post with Vue and I understand the basics of it using axios to do some Ajax and Vue to do some changes to the DOM that reflect the current state.

But so far I have only tried single post. What happens if I have multiple posts like this on one page? How do I manage the Ajax calls? And most importantly how would I make the Vue handle each post independently in terms of DOM changes?

I'm new to this so if someone would drop some dummy code to clarify this problem, that would be super helpful, thanks.

Comment: You would create a post component. Each component handles its own ajax call and DOM updates, and you only need to write the code for the component once. You can create as many post components as you need, they should all work independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When requesting your posts to your page, via a GET method I suppose, pass a unique identifier to each post, the id would work perfectly here.
Make you controller work so as to add entries to a pivot table that contains the id of the user and the id of the post. When writing your logic for the like function, make a vue method that has as an argument the id of the post, and pass that key in the data of an axios post request and do the processing in Laravel as you'll normally do.